# Dynamic enum converter

Tags: c#, wpf, markup-extensions

I want to create a dynamic 2-way-converter for all possible enums in my application.

I don't want to have to create a converter for each enum, I want to create one converter that provides converting from enum to byte and from byte to enum vice versa.

How can I get there? My approach is already 2-way but requires a static cast **(MyEnum)** in the code:

```
public class MyEnumConverter : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter 
        {
        public object Convert(object value, System.Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
            return (MyEnum)value;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, System.Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
            return (byte)value;
        }

        public override object ProvideValue(System.IServiceProvider serviceProvider) {
            return this;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You mix byte and int.  And can you post how you are binding to the Enum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can do this 2 different ways.

Option 1: Take advantage of the `targetType` parameter on the convert methods. When you need to convert to the enum, then `targetType` is the enum type. You can use one of the static methods on the `System.Enum` class to do the conversion.

Option 2: In your xaml, use the ConverterParameter to pass in the enum type you want to convert to:

```
Converter={local:MyConverter, ConverterParameter={x:Type MyEnumType}}
```

If you go that route, then the type will be in the `parameter` parameter of the convert methods. Again, the static methods on the `System.Enum` class will do the heavy lifting for you.

Answer (score 1):

Try these extension methods, It will convert from enum to datatype(int, byte,..) and from datatype(int, byte,..) to enum vice versa..

```
    public static T ToEnumValue<T, E>(this E enumType)
    {
        return (T)Enum.ToObject(typeof(E), enumType);
    }

    public static E ToEnumType<T, E>(this T enumString)
    {
        return (E)Enum.Parse(typeof(E), enumString.ToString());
    }
```

Ex: To use the above methods, Take a enum

```
public enum EmployeeType
{
    Permanent = 0,
    Contract = 1,
}

int value = EmployeeType.Contract.ToEnumValue<int, EmployeeType>(); // 1
EmployeeType employeeType = value.ToEnumType<int, EmployeeType>();  // Contract
```