# How to create a generic EnumConverter in Windows Universal App

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1, win-universal-app

I have a Windows Universal App in which I need to create a generic Enum Converter.

Here's the first look at the converter I tried to create.

```
public class EnumConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, System.Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return System.Enum.GetName(targetType, value);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, System.Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return System.Enum.Parse(targetType, value as string, false);
    }
}
```

However the target type is "System.Object" instead of Enum type hence the conversion is failing.

I already looked at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13365384/dynamic-enum-converter) and tried to follow both the options.
Option-A did not work because targettype is System.Object instead of my Enum

Option-B did not work because WinRt-Xaml doesn't have x:Type to give in the converter parameter.

The [EnumConverter from Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.enumconverter(v=vs.110).aspx) is unavailable.

I would be very glad if someone can point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`targetType` parameter defines a type, in which `value` is being converted to. If you want to get the type of enumeration, you have to use `value.GetType`:

```
public object Convert(object value, System.Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
{
    return Enum.GetName(value.GetType(), value);
}
```

but there's an easy way:

```
public object Convert(object value, System.Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
{
    return value.ToString();
}
```